# How can I disable Ninja forms tooltip?

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

Is there some way to disable input tooltip when the number is higher or lower in Ninja forms (e.g currecy input)?

The tooltip has certain string "Please select a value than is no more than *int-val* "

[image]

I searched (greped) that certain string in every file on WP Ninja forms plugins folder, but couldn't find anything that relates to the tooltip functionality.

I just wish to remove the tooltip, any suggestions would be welcome.